# Single host CSV

Tags: windows, hyper-v, cluster, file-server

I have a single physical server with directly attached SAS storage that I run Hyper-V on and within it all of the machines on my lab (AD, Exchange, SQL, SCCM, SCOM, File Servers, etc).

I am trying to create a guest file server cluster with two nodes, so that I can easily patch the guests without having to worry about disconnecting any applications that are potentially using storage on the file servers.

For this purpose, I am looking to use shared VHDX files between the two file servers, but it seems that the host storage needs to be CSV for that, which in turn requires a one node cluster.

However, the issue I am encountering is that even though one node clusters are possible and supported, it seems that creating a cluster (of any kind) always requires the cluster nodes to be joined to AD (even when creating a AD Detached Cluster, new to Server 2012 R2). So in my particular case this appears to be a chicken and egg sort of situation:

The AD server is running as a VM on the physical server, but I can't have it running there before creating the CSV and to do so I need to have the physical server joined to the domain.

Any thoughts on this matter and is this something someone had done before?

By the way, I am really keen on trying the shared VHDX files so am not really looking for third party software alternatives like StarWind iSCSI software or so.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the SVHDX filter on a single Hyper-V host, without CSV.  This, of course, defeats much of the point of Shared VHDX, as you have a single point of failure.  And because of this, you're in unsupported territory.  But since your question clearly spells out that you want a file server cluster on an unclustered host, this is probably the solution for you.  The following blog post outlines the steps:

http://www.aidanfinn.com/?p=15145

Comment: That is absolutely what I was after, thank you. One thing to note (which was implied from what the article said) is that the command needs to be re-run every time the host starts up, so I've created a scheduled task for it. This is something the article probably could have included.